# Sitecore User Group Directory

Tags: community

Around the world, there are lot of Sitecore User Groups created/maintained/organized by sitecore community.

What is the website which contains all the Sitecore User Groups listed in same place ?

Comment: We've since set up a Community Wiki aiming to answer this question more comprehensively. But the question was an excellent eye-opener to the need for answering these types of questions - thank you :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of an official listing, but [www.sitecoreug.org](http://sitecoreug.org/) looks pretty complete. You can also search on [www.Meetup.com](http://www.meetup.com), where most user groups are listed.

Comment: SitecoureUG.org is missing some. I happened to find this wiki where the editors were quick and happy to add the one that they were missing. Now it is complete (to the best of my knowledge): https://www.reddit.com/r/sitecore/wiki/user-groups