# Where to list a new blog about Sitecore?

Tags: community

Our team began to write blog posts about Sitecore.

How can I let the Sitecore community know that there's a new interesting blog? What channels can I use to promote it?

Comment: I have edited your question to remove self-promotion, as it isn't allowed on this site. Now that your question is a general one (rather than focused on a specific blog), other users will be able to benefit from the answers in the future

Comment: See also: http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1689/how-can-i-connect-with-the-sitecore-community

Answer (score 5):

You can also post to the various Social Media groups:

Sitecore group on Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/groups/6932529533/

Sitecore group on LinkedIn: https://www.linkedin.com/groups/71381

Sitecore Developer group on LinkedIn: https://www.linkedin.com/groups/3066050

Sitecore on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/sitecore/

You can also get your post added to the Sitcore Links collection: http://sitecore.link/Suggest

Don't forget, it perfectly valid to provide links to your own blog posts on answers here on StackExchange and also on StackOverflow - just be mindful not to provide Link-Only answers (i.e. if the blog post was to disappear the answer should still be valid on it's own)

Answer (score 3):

Join SitecoreChat Slack: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScsJX9PC3m8u-labRn_BNnByR0aiAxPYowN-doed6_t45aPhg/viewform

There is a #blogfeed channel. Contact with admin to include your rss feed there.

Answer (score 2):

You can request to be included in the [Sitecore feed](http://feeds.sitecore.net/) here: https://community.sitecore.net/general/f/11/t/4183

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of channels available, but allow me to start by stating the obvious. For people to catch attention to your blog it must, indeed, be interesting. If it is, the Sitecore community will link to your posts, refer to your posts, tweet about your posts and promotion comes on its own.

That said, and I'm including answers already given here, here is where I would start:

- Join Slack - as @Marek points out. There is an invite form at https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScsJX9PC3m8u-labRn_BNnByR0aiAxPYowN-doed6_t45aPhg/viewform
- Get your blog into the official Sitecore Blog Feed (http://feeds.sitecore.net/) - request to be included here: https://community.sitecore.net/general/f/11/t/4183
- Tweet. Not just when you post, but start participating in the Sitecore community banter on Twitter. Use @Sitecore and #sitecore to be noticed and eventually gain followers.
- Update your personal profile, here, on Slack, on Twitter
- Present at your local Sitecore User Group, get your name out there. And you have an intro slide for shameless self promotion ;-)

And just keep at it. Over time, your blog will attract more and more SEO juice. Don't be discouraged if the response isn't overwhelming right at the start.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for help, Mark. I know, audience never come immediatelly. But you always can help it little. And what is better place to ask how, then here in middle of sitecore bloggers? :-) We will follow your recommendation, thx.