# Sitecore 8.2 integrated search function with Salesforce

Tags: content-search, indexing

This is my first question for SE...and forgive my lack of technical expertise in this area.

We're building a our new website on Sitecore which has to be integrated with Salesforce. In Saleforce, we will have our 'Community' section which we need searchable when in the Sitecore area of the website as it contains a lot of useful resources not kept in the Sitecore DB...

e.g. As a user, I am searching a topic on our website, however some of these resources will be in Salesforce.  How can the search return results from the Salesforce and Sitecore areas of the digital estate?

Any guidance would be useful as I am trying to establish feasibility.

Many thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Lack of technical expertise is not a problem, welcome to the site :-)   However, your question is going to have trouble here, as it is really a bit broad and more up for discussion than something that can be easily answered. You should also check out our Slack and Community forums - more information here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1689/how-can-i-connect-with-the-sitecore-community

Comment: I do not know whether you are going to build your own connector for Salesforce or use existed but at least you can try to build or extend your search with Salesforce Connect 1.4.1. This version is for Sitecore 8.