# Third Party custom controls for Sitecore

Tags: mvc

Does anyone know of a suite of third-party custom controls that are available for purchase for Sitecore? Or are you just using the standard VS third-party tools?

We are going to start rewriting our ASXP everything (layouts and controls) to MVC (renders) for Sitecore.  It would be nice to have some standard controls already written.

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, you are looking for the Sitecore MVC based Solution/Project and ready-made foundational components (like Caching, Multi-Site, Publishing, Search etc.). Am I right?

Comment: If you sign up for the Slack Community there are a number of folks that can help through discussion. Otherwise I think SXA is a really good option. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1689/how-can-i-connect-with-the-sitecore-community/1690#1690

Comment: Here is an example of what I want.  Someone in-house developed a "promo header" which is a carousel with limited functionality and not well-written.  Moving forward I would like to use something like Owl Carousel and have Sitecore-specific functionality built around it such as templates and renderings.    That is just one example and I was hoping someone had a suite of these controls.  Maybe it's something i need to write and market.  LOL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not 3rd party - but you really should look into the [Sitecore Experience Accelerator](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator) - while it doesn't have "controls" in the way you are thinking, it comes with a number of components/renderings that you can use to build pages and then you can build your theme to style those components.

It is also very easy to build other components that you can use with SXA that follow the pattern.

This way you have a nice standardized set of components, that all follow a good Sitecore architecture, you have a lot of built in additions like Sitemap, Robots.txt, Redirects etc... Boiler plate stuff that you would normally have to build yourself. It really does save a lot of effort in the build.

Also, you don't have to think too much about the information architecture, as there is already a good pattern to follow.