# Sitecore Developer community in India

Tags: sitecore-commerce

Appologies in advance, if it's a wrong platform to ask this question, but the I don't see any other platform either.

I am looking to join a Sitecore community/meetup anywhere in India where I can learn from other peeps and also meet local Sitecore developers. Can someone please connect me to it? Can be digital as well.

Regards
Gaurav Sharma

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because these questions belong to https://community.sitecore.net or Sitecore Slack.

Comment: Join the sitecore slack channel https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScsJX9PC3m8u-labRn_BNnByR0aiAxPYowN-doed6_t45aPhg/viewform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark has already given the answer on “how to connect with Sitecore community” Please check it here
[How can I connect with the Sitecore Community?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1689/how-can-i-connect-with-the-sitecore-community)

However, you can also find the below Sitecore user group in India:

Sitecore User Group Hyderabad - https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Hyderabad/
Sitecore user group Delhi NCR - https://www.linkedin.com/in/sugncr/
Sitecore user group Bangalore - http://sugblr.in/, https://www.facebook.com/sugblr/
Sitecore user group India - http://www.sugcon.in/, https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-India/members/?op=leaders

You can find more details on Meetup, Linkedin, Facebook, etc, I suggest you to connect the local Sitecore user group which is convenient for you to attend the monthly meetups, where you can get connected with many other Sitecore folks.

Also, you can check the online webinar, you will get the notification on meetup, Facebook, LinkedIn once you join the group.

Comment: I heard recently from my former colleague that there is also SUG in Chennai :) http://sugchennai.in . Please add it to your list ;)