# Run setting value of config file on ContentDelivery server only

Tags: sxa, configuration

We would like to run particular setting value on ContentDelivery or ContentManagement server only in Sitecore 9.1.1.

Config file

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <services>
      <configurator type="name, assembly name" />    
    </services>
    <settings>
      <setting name="Name" value="web"     require="ContentDelivery" />
      <setting name="Name" value="master" require="ContentManagement"  />
    </settings>
    <mvc>
      <precompilation>
        <assemblies>
          <assemblyIdentity name="project name" />
        </assemblies>
      </precompilation>
    </mvc>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

We have added require attribute (`require="ContentDelivery"` ) but it's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore>
    <services>
      <configurator type="name, assembly name" />    
    </services>
    <settings>
      <setting name="Name" value="web"     role:require="ContentDelivery" />
      <setting name="Name" value="master" role:require="ContentManagement"  />
    </settings>
    <mvc>
      <precompilation>
        <assemblies>
          <assemblyIdentity name="project name" />
        </assemblies>
      </precompilation>
    </mvc>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Note the "*role:require*" instead of require and the *xmlns:role* at the top as differences.

Comment: Not able to fetch the value of `Name` in code in CM server (Local)

Comment: Is your role set correctly? You should first check the resulting config with /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx to make sure that is correct (the issue could be in the code as well).

Comment: In config file, content delivery and content management role are not showing anywhere. Do we need to create these roles in local instance as well if they are not showing?

Comment: Your local instance is probably a Standalone version. But that is an assumption.. You might want to join us on Slack as I do think you have other issues - or at least show us your role config.

Comment: any link for Slack where I can join ?

Comment: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/1690/237